# Sending data to server in json format

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I created a div for comments in run time using jQuery and want to save these comments in a database so that the comments appear with a date after the page reloads.

I know that I should send it in an ajax request but don't know how, any help?

```
       $('body').append('<div class="chat-container"><textarea class="chat-textbox" placeholder="Start a discussion here..."></textarea><input type="submit" class="chat-send" value="Send" /></div><div class="chat-content"></div>');
$('.chat-send').attr('disabled', true);
$('input[type="text"],textarea').on('keyup',function() {
var textarea_value = $(".chat-textbox").val();
if(textarea_value == '') {
 $(".chat-send").click(function(){
 var newComment = ($('.chat-textbox').val())
      var newDate= ($.datepicker.formatDate('dd / mm / yy', new Date()));
        $('.chat-content').append('<div class="new-comment"><label class="currentDate"></label>'+newComment+'</div>');
        $('.currentDate').text(newDate);
        $('.chat-textbox').val('');`enter code here`
        $('.chat-send').attr('disabled', true);
  });
```

Comment: I would suggest you take a look at the [$.ajax documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) and try some of the examples from there.

Comment: Is a bit hard to understand what you are asking. You mean you want to post the comments to the server and store them in the database? Nothing more? If that is correct you should check [JQuery.post](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) and try to use the code examples there. You will need to implement the server side that will receive the request and store it in the database as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply send you json data along with your ajax request. You can do it as follows.

```
var arr = { message: 'Hello mate', date: '21233244223', user_id: 234};
$.ajax({
    url: '<your_api_url_here>',
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify(arr),
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    async: false,
    success: function(msg) {
        alert(msg);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To send data as json, you can use `ajax post`. Add this inside on click handler for `chat-send` class:

```
$(".chat-send").click(function() {
    ......

    var comment = {
        "date": newDate,
        "comment": newComment
    };

    // your post url here
    var post_url = ....;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: post_url,
        data: JSON.stringify(comment),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
        },
        failure: function(error) {
            alert(error);
        }
    });
});
```